# Regex selector to select all html tags except the <img> and <b> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, user-interface, tags, frontend

Hi I am trying to write a regex pattern that selects all HTML tags except for the  `<img>` and `<b>` tags.

I am trying to work with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Sm4Azv/1) but no progress.

```
(<(?:a|p|img)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead for `b` or `img` after the opening `<`:

```
(<(?!(?:b|img)\b)[^>]+>)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PPJJ2n/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using word boundary (`\b`)

```
(<(?:b|img)\b[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/niPx11/1)**